# Room is very inconvinient... what's ther problem?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room

I'v got the error

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle memolist(com.jakchang.savelocation.Entity.MemoEntity).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='memolist', columns={date=Column{
name='date', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, fontType=Column{name='fontType', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
address=Column{name='address', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
nation=Column{name='nation', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
city=Column{name='city', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
uri2=Column{name='uri2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
uri3=Column{name='uri3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
 uri1=Column{name='uri1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
isDeleted=Column{name='isDeleted', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, 
tag=Column{name='tag', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
text=Column{name='text', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
uri4=Column{name='uri4', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, 
longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},
 foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
```

I think I wrote right way the entity.. but I got the error.
I'm using livedata with mvvm.
Please Let me know to solve this....

```
Entity

@Entity(tableName = "memolist")
public class MemoEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="latitude")
    String latitude;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="longitude")
    String longitude;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="nation")
    String nation;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="city")
    String city;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="address")
    String address;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="title")
    String title;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="tag")
    String tag;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="date")
    String date;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="uri1")
    String uri1;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="uri2")
    String uri2;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="uri3")
    String uri3;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="uri4")
    String uri4;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="text")
    String text;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="fontType")
    String fontType;
    @ColumnInfo(name ="isDeleted")
    String isDeleted;

    public MemoEntity(){}
    getter/setter~~
}
```

is it important to match the below tableinfo sequence and entity sequence?
hard to study alone....
really I wanna solve this...

Comment: increase room version

Comment: It's because there's a change in Entity structure. You may have added new value or removed an old value. If it's not a live app, you can clear the app data/uninstall the app and install again. For live app(with playstore users), increase the room version code. You can also write migration strategy.

Comment: I never added or removed anything. with my hope, I tried migration 1 to 2 that is nothing to do. but the error is same....many times I tried to install and unistall...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the error message and especially the differences between *excepted* and *found*. It can be an issue with a default value in your migration script.

For example, using the Room 2.1.0 and adding a new integer in my Entity, I have set a default value :

```
object MIGRATION_1_2 : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE entity ADD COLUMN newInteger INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got the error " android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: entity (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])"  but I wrote      public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "memo")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .build();

        return appDatabase;
    }     why I have no table?

Comment: replace *entity* in my previous answer by your own entity. I think it is *memolist*. Same for the *newInteger* attribute, put your own field you have added